# Adding Icon to Main Menu

Tags: magento-1.9

trying to add Icon left to the each Category menu, found top.phtml where it displays home icon, have to modify that somehow? code:

```
<?php
/**
 * $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml() supports optional arguments:
 * int Level number for list item class to start from
 * string Extra class of outermost list items
 * string If specified wraps children list in div with this class
 */
?>
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0,'level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<nav class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
    <?php $_anyActive = false; 
          foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category) { 
              $_anyActive = $_anyActive || $this->isCategoryActive($_category); 
          } 
            ?>
          <li class="level1 nav-0 level-top top parent <?php echo !$_anyActive ? 'active' : '' ?>">
              <a class="active-bghome" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>"><span><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/img-home.png') ?>" alt=""/></span></a>
          </li>
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php endif ?>
```

output: [image]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to split visuals and code. So add a unique identifier based on ID or slug, add your custom styling in your stylesheet.

for instance:

```
nav-primary li.nav-1:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('path/to/image.png');
  width: 10px;
  display: block;
  height: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add changes to this top.phtml and it your custom theme

just add like below after `<ul>` tag

```
<nav class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
       <li class="classname_for_icon"> home icon </li>
    <?php $_anyActive = false; 
          foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category) { 
              $_anyActive = $_anyActive || $this->isCategoryActive($_category); 
          } 
            ?>
          <li class="level1 nav-0 level-top top parent <?php echo !$_anyActive ? 'active' : '' ?>">
              <a class="active-bghome" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('')?>"><span><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/img-home.png') ?>" alt=""/></span></a>
          </li>
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to remove `home` icon and need `icons` before every `category item`.

For removing `HOME Icon` just put this code in comments

```
<span>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/img-home.png') ?>" alt=""/>
</span>
```

and to add icons after every category Item add this code

```
<li>
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('source_for_category_icon_image') ?>" alt=""/>
</li>
```

before

`<?php echo $_menu ?>`

Comment: Home icon is ok, what I need[1]: http://i.imgur.com/pP84Tgr.png
Second code adds icons as a separate category

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to add category image to the top navigation.
You can modify this code according to your requirement to have both image or any other icon and category name as well.
Rewriting Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer like below

```
class Custom_CategoryImage_Model_Observer extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer {

    public function addCategoryImages(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        $block->addCacheTag(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::CACHE_TAG);
        $this->_addCategoriesToMenu(
            Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories(), $observer->getMenu(), $block, true
        );
    }

    public function _addCategoriesToMenu($categories, $parentCategoryNode, $menuBlock, $addTags = false) {
        $categoryModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
                continue;
            }

            $nodeId = 'category-node-' . $category->getId();

            $categoryModel->setId($category->getId());
            if ($addTags) {
                $menuBlock->addModelTags($categoryModel);
            }

            $tree = $parentCategoryNode->getTree();
            $categoryData = array(
                'name' => $category->getName(),
                'id' => $nodeId,
                'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
                'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
                'thumbnail' => $categoryModel->load($category->getId())->getThumbnail()
            );
            $categoryNode = new Varien_Data_Tree_Node($categoryData, 'id', $tree, $parentCategoryNode);
            $parentCategoryNode->addChild($categoryNode);

            $flatHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat');
            if ($flatHelper->isEnabled() && $flatHelper->isBuilt(true)) {
                $subcategories = (array) $category->getChildrenNodes();
            } else {
                $subcategories = $category->getChildren();
            }

            $this->_addCategoriesToMenu($subcategories, $categoryNode, $menuBlock, $addTags);
        }
    }

}
```

config.xml for your extension will look something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_CategoryImage>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Custom_CategoryImage>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <categoryImage>
                <class>Custom_CategoryImage_Model</class>
            </categoryImage>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <observer>Custom_CategoryImage_Model_Observer</observer>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Modify it according to your need.